# How to generate zip file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using .Net framework 2.0. I need to create zip file from the folder path"D:\Nagaraj\New Project Read Document\TCBILPOS\TCBILPOS\TCBILPOS\FileBuild\HOST" ...within that host folder has 7 txt file. so,Now I want to create zip file "HOST.zip" in this same folder path "D:\Nagaraj\New Project Read Document\TCBILPOS\TCBILPOS\TCBILPOS\FileBuild"........thanks in advance

Comment: This might help you. http://forums.asp.net/t/1086292.aspx

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426992/how-to-create-zip-file-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/10/25/creating-zip-archives-in-net-without-an-external-library-like-sharpziplib.aspx)

You can choose to use a third party library or you can use J# (which has had zipping included to keep compatibility with the Java libraries). Full source code in that link.

Answer (score 0):

There a a huge number of [zipping libraries](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), but personally I usually start a [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) process with the appropriate command line switches.

Answer (score 0):

without using 3rd party.. we can do it by using J# libraries with C#. 
just add a reference to the vjslib.dll  and add these namespaces.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using java.io;
using java.util.zip;
using System.IO;
using System.Text
```

Now mix of j# and C# comes into picture. The classes `FileOutputStream` `ZipOutputStream` `FileInputStream` and `ZipEntry` are j# classes which plays important roles in zip compression.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string ZipFileName = String.Format(@"C:\ZippedFolders\({0}).MyZip.zip",DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
    string theDirectory = @"C:\Sarat";

    try
    {
        sb.Append(String.Format("Directory To Zip: {0}.<br/>", theDirectory));
        sb.Append(String.Format("Zip file: {0}.<br/>", ZipFileName));

        string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(theDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(ZipFileName))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(ZipFileName);
            sb.Append(String.Format("Deleted old Zip file: {0}.<br/>", ZipFileName));
        }


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ZipFileName);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        zos.setLevel(9);

        for (int i = 0; i < allFiles.Length; i++ )
        {
            string sourceFile = allFiles[i];

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(sourceFile.Replace(theDirectory + @"\", ""));
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);

            sbyte[] buffer = new sbyte[1024];
            int len;

            while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) >= 0)
            {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            fis.close();
        }

        zos.closeEntry();
        zos.close();
        fos.close();

        sb.Append(String.Format("Folder {0} Zipped successfuly to File {1}.<br/>", theDirectory, ZipFileName));


    }
    catch (Exception eX)
    {
        sb.Append(String.Format("Error zipping folder {0}. Details: {1}. Stack Trace: {2}.<br/>", theDirectory, eX.Message, eX.StackTrace));
    }
```