# Download folder on click of a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to download a folder not zip folder on a click of a button in Webforms? For downloading a file I usually do:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.TransmitFile(fileName);
Response.End();
```

But this does not seem to work for a folder. I'm not too sure if it's even possible to download a folder via asp.net webforms.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: No there is no way. You need to zip it.

Comment: It's not possible with any system, and not just asp.net. Even systems that might seem able to do it disguise it as multiple single-file downloads.

Comment: @VDWWD Zip the folder on the server where I'm downloading from in code on the click event?

Comment: Yep. There are libraries out there to zip a file or folder. Then use your code above to download that zip. Perhaps it can even be done in a MemoryStream without creating an actual zip file on disk.

Comment: I don't think it's possible because the folder is not a isolated entity like a file and it's just a way to organize files, Maybe you can handle it on the client site for example get folder name and create it then download files to it.

Comment: @VDWWD would it be possible if you can provide an example with being it done in MemoryStream please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426992/how-to-create-zip-file-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

You need to zip the folder and then download it as a single file. Even Microsoft and Google do so. :) Btw, it is rather easy since .Net Framework has specific classes to zip, see [System.IO.Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression?view=netframework-4.7.2) namespace.

I used a [third-party control](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxFileManagerAndUploadDemos/FileManager/MultipleFileSelection.aspx) for this purpose, though my task was a bit simpler. I needed to download multiple files selected by an end-user, but not an entire folder. It is possible that that control can automate folder downloading, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading a folder is not possible!

Please consider downloading the folder contents as a compressed file, preferrably Zip file.

earlier Projects where I have allowed to upload documents for offline processing, once the documents were verified and signed user was given an option to either download all the documents as a compressed file each file individually.

I've also provided alternate versions of compressed files like Zip, 7-Zi, etc,.